# Digital signature slowing down DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, digital-signature

I’m facing a very strange issue: I have a DLL developed in C++ & Visual Studio which have been working fine for some years (being constantly updated). Recently I noticed that when moved to other PCs was slowing down the performance. As an example, I measured a function that takes around 120ms to be executed in my PC (Win7, Core i3 second generation), but in a brand new PC (Win10, Core i5 8th generation) takes around 700ms, which didn't make sense (this very same effect happens in any PC).

After two days of testing and trying different optimizations approaches (linker, compiler, platforms, etc) I realised that performance was normal when the DLL was not signed.

This delay is not caused the first time that it is used, but in any function call while the application is running.

I didn't mention that this DLL is being used from a C# program.

The signature was provided by Comodo and applied to the DLL using signtool.exe

I would appreciate any clue or information that could clarify the source of this issue.

Comment: Does the Win7 system actually check the signature? Can you verify the behaviour of signed/unsigned on both systems? The other thing worth checking would be the crypto provider used for signature verification (that's probably something internal to the .Net Platform since it's invoked from C#?).

Comment: How do I find out whether Win7 is checking the signature or not?
Do you think is this something to do with the time that takes to verify the signature? In that case, is this done for every function call?

Comment: If Win7 is not checking the signature, it is obviously cheating >:) Just break the signature for a quick answer (use mismatching key for signing) or google it. It is weird the signature has to be checked per function call, maybe you're invoking `dllopen` too often - can you perhaps cache the extracted functions addresses? (sorry if it makes no sense, taking a guess here)

Comment: @hauron thanks for your time, but this does not fix the issues. Is it normal that a digital signature has a negative effect in the performance of a DLL? I would find this normal if the DLL would be encrypted, but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Encryption is a different story, not sure how they relate in Windows library loading, but I can easily imagine a DLL that's just signed. I'm sorry, but I do not know the right answer, beyond the intuition shared before.

Comment: Thanks anyway @hauron